# Array of object - all object are equal the last one javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript objects and push all of them into array and retrieve them later.

I have a `history` object, and `pushHistory()` method. Also I have also a `History` object. It looks like:

```
  public history: History[];

  pushHistory(cell, support, pad, empty, time){
    let historyObject = new History(cell, support, pad, empty, time);
    this.history.push(historyObject);    
  }
```

When I want retrieve any history value, for example `history[X].data.cell[0][0].value` it is always equal the last value. Generally it look like all `History` instance is the same instance, so in my `history` array it's only one object, always refer to the last version.

My History object look a like:

```
export class History {
  public cells: Cell[][];
  public support: Support[];
  public pad: Pad[];
  public empty: number;
  public lastTime: ITimer;

  constructor(cells: Cell[][], support: Support[], pad: Pad[], empty: number, lastTime: ITimer) {
    this.cells = cells;
    this.support = support;
    this.pad = pad;
    this.empty = empty;
    this.lastTime = lastTime;
  }
}
```

As you ask for `Component` code. `setValue` method is called from .html button click, `this.cells` come from Android object (form android app).

```
export class Componenet implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TimerComponent) timer: TimerComponent;

  cells: Cells[][];
  support: Support[];
  pad: Pad[];
  empty: number;
  time: ITimer;
  enumMode: enum;
  enumAction: enum;
  testValue: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private history: HisotryService, private soundService: AudioPlayerService) {
    this.enumMode = Mode;
    this.enumAction = Action;
    this.testValue = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.empty = 10;

    if (typeof Android != 'undefined') {
      this.cells = Android.generate();
}


    this.cells = [];
    this.pad = [];
    this.support= [];

    this.history.retriveHistoryObject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last')));
    const historyObject = this.history.getLastHistoryObject();

    this.cells = historyObject.cells;
    this.support = historyObject.support;
    this.pad = historyObject.pad;

    this.empty = historyObject.emptyCells;

    this.timerStart = historyObject.lastTime;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.timer.startTimer();
    }, 1000);

  }


  public setValue(number, usage) {
    this.soundService.playClick();

    // CODE that maek operation on this.cells, this.pad, this.empty and so on

    this.history.pushHistory(this.cells, null, this.pad, this.empty, time);

  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `History` class look like?

Comment: @JunKang - I add history object structure into my question

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What is data? Are you sure that data isn't containing an instance of something that is actually shared, ie each one holding the same reference to the same object

Comment: When I add for example `console.log(historyObject.cells[0][0].value)` before push it's always OK. This is also OK after push:  `console.log(this.history[this.history.length - 1].cells[0][0].value);` but this after a push: `console.log(this.history[this.history.length - 2].cells[0][0].value);` return the same value - it should be last but one version.

Comment: You need to show `a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` if you expect anyone to be able to help you. Show us how you're calling `pushHistory()` and what you're passing into it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand class idea in TypeScript and it's not like in Java, and new Object it's not a new object, but the same Object with new data? Maybe I should copy object before push?

Comment: post the code where you call the `pushHistory`

Comment: Your solution is not a solution. It's a hack. If you want to ask people for help on SO, than please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please pass your solution as an answer not as an edit to the question

Comment: as others already said, sho the code calling `pushHistory`

Comment: I add component code where I call `pushHistory` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `cloneDeep`. It creates a new object instance instead of referencing the same object.

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

...

export class ... implements OnInit {

  ...


  public setValue() {
    ...
    const historyCopy = cloneDeep(historyObject);
    this.history.push(historyCopy);
  }
}
```